# assetPath returns different Urls

Tags: grails, groovy, asset-pipeline, grails-plugin, gsp

I am using Grails 2.4.4 and compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9" with compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.2".

My config.groovy has the following entries:

```
grails.serverURL = "http://mydomain.no-ip.biz:8080/myapp"
grails.serverName = "mydomain.no-ip.biz"
```

When I use

```
${assetPath(src: 'logoSmall.png', absolute: true)}
```

on a GSP view I get the following url:

```
http://mydomain.no-ip.biz:8080/myapp/assets/logoSmall.png
```

Which is the correct url.

When I render the GSP view in a Service with:

```
PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer
...

def contents = groovyPageRenderer.render(template: "/pathToMyGSP", model:[])
```

I the contents view my path becomes:

http://mydomain.no-ip.biz:8080/myappassets/logoSmall.png
Note that the / before the assets disappeared. This happens only when I use groovyPageRenderer.render when I use g.render it does not happen.

**How do I get the correct asset url?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This bug has been fixed](https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/issues/196) in a more recent version of the asset-pipeline plugin (2.0.21, I think).

Comment: The problem is that version > 2.0 does not work with sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.2

Comment: Until the `sass-asset-pipeline` is updated, I think all you can do is to make this change locally in `asset-pipeline:1.9.9` https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/commit/7135ec919e7e1a1c4c681fe91420b94f877f09b1